# Best practice for using interface type as model in View and use real type attributes and validations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have such interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And I have some view models implement it:

```
public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    [Display(Name = "Foo1 Amount")]
    [Range(6, 11)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{       
    [Display(Name = "Foo2 Amount")]
    [Range(1, 5)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to create a new view for each of `Foo1` and `Foo2`.

So, I have created a view which has `IFoo` type model.

```
@model IFoo

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Amount)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Amount)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Amount)
</div>
```

But, **it doesn't create client-side unobtrusive attributes** like `Range` attribute in client-side.

If I create a new view for each of this types, then everyting will be ok.

**Update:** I have tried to change interface to abstract class as offered in the answer, but it didn't help neither.

Comment: How would it know? `IFoo` doesn't have that attribute. It would be unreasonable to try to search the type hierarchy for derived classes, with potentially conflicting type attributes.

Comment: @siride I understand you.But, `@Model.GetType()` is `Foo1` or `Foo2`. And I thought they might use this for getting validation attributes.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - Did you try like this - `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => ((IFoo)x).Amount)`  and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => ((IFoo)x).Amount)` ??

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I have not tried this, because it could not work. But, I have tried it anyway and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this using an interface. When you use a html helper to generate html, it first generates the `ModelMetadata` for the property (in the case of the strongly typed html helpers, by calling

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
```

This generates the metadata based on the **property** taking into account its attributes. In  the case of `TextBoxFor()`, the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of `HtmlHelper` is then called to generate the `data-val-*` attributes.

The key here is that its the metadata for the **property**, and the property its getting the metadata for does not have any validation attributes. And further to your comment *"@Model.GetType() is Foo1 or Foo2"*, it does not attempt to get an instance of the concrete type and generate its metadata.

Unless you were to create your own ModelMetadataProvider and override the CreateMetadata() method, you need to create separate views for each concrete class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To tell the truth I have created custom providers based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311907/model-inheritance-possible-when-using-strongly-typed-view-in-mvc3/8320821#8320821). This is working, but I have to create some providerfor fluent validation also. But, I have no time for this now. So, I will create a view per each concret class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you instead use an abstract or just use a base class, define the Amount property with some default range and override in the subclass.

```
public abstract class Test
{
    protected int _number;
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(0, 10)]
    public abstract int NumProp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class Test2 : Test
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(100, 1000)]
    public override int NumProp
    {
        get{
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not overriding the attribute.

Comment: have you tried removing the attribute from the base class?

Comment: Yes, then it doesn't adding anything.

Comment: well damn!  Interfaces don't allow attributes to inherit into the implementations so this was my best guess at it.

Comment: I guess you'l  have to create your property and handle it yourself.